# Date Mongodb with Node y Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an api with node, express and mongodb

## Save

```
function SaveOfferDay(req, res){
    var update = req.body;
    var id = req.params.id;

    Offer.update(   {"_id": id},{"$addToSet": {"date": {"day" : new Date("2018-
                12-04"),}}}, (err, offerUpdated) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición'});
        return res.status(200).send({offer: offerUpdated});

    });
}
```

2018-12-04T00:00:00.000Z

and I want the date to be

2018-12-04T23:00:00.000Z

NOW I want to make a query, where I show all the results after this date.

## query

```
function getOffer(req, res){
    var cityId = req.params.city;
    var hoy = new Date();



    if(req.params.page){
        var page = req.params.page;
    }else{
        var page = 1;
    }

    var itemsPerPage = 4;

    Offer.find({city:cityId,'date.day' : {"$gte" :'2018-12-05' }
    }).sort('name').paginate(page, itemsPerPage, function(err, offers,
    total){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición.'});
        }else{
            if(!offers){
                res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe!! !!'});
            }else{

                return res.status(200).send({
                    total_items: total,
                    offers: offers
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**Here is the question**

When I make a query and I want you to return the records for that day, they are not found. I've been looking and the problem is the time at which the record is saved.

Let's see if anyone can understand me what I mean

Answer (score 0):

in the end i have not known how to do it, but I found another solution

I think it could be fine, at least it works for me.

I have used **momentjs**, to make a search of the date, without taking into account the timem

**moment(new Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')**

```
var moment = require('moment');

function getOffer(req, res){
    var cityId = req.params.city;
    var hoy = new Date();



    if(req.params.page){
    var page = req.params.page;
    }else{
    var page = 1;
    }

    var itemsPerPage = 4;

Offer.find({city:cityId,'date.day' : {"$gte" :moment(new Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY') }
}).sort('name').paginate(page, itemsPerPage, function(err, offers,
total){
    if(err){
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la petición.'});
    }else{
        if(!offers){
            res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe!! !!'});
        }else{

            return res.status(200).send({
                total_items: total,
                offers: offers
            });
        }

    }
});
}
```

Whoever wants to, can you give me your opinion, I would appreciate it